# prolog - counting node in a binary tree

Tags: prolog

I have a different request than what I saw on stackoverflow. Say my binary tree is of the form `tree(Node, Leafs)`. There is no left or right leafs, only the attribute `leafs`.

How would you go about counting the node in that tree?

For example the tree could be:

```
tree(node1, [tree(node2)]), tree(node3, []), tree(node4, [tree(node6,[tree(node2,[])]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *unordered binary tree* is a tree where each node can have up to two children, but the order between the children is not important. Thus, each node in a non-empty unordered binary tree can be represented as a term of the form `tree(Node,Children)`, where `Children` is an empty set (if `Node` is a leaf), or a set of one or two trees (if `Node` is an internal node). An empty unordered tree can be represented as `nil`. To simplify the implementation, we can represent sets as lists. For example, the unordered binary tree:

```
    a
   / \
  b   c
 / \  |
d   e f
```

can be represented as:

```
mytree(tree(a,
            [tree(b,
                  [tree(d,[]),
                   tree(e,[])]),
             tree(c,
                  [tree(f,[])])])).
```

To count the nodes in an unordered binary tree, we can use [`maplist/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3) and [`sum_list/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sum_list/2) as following:

```
count_nodes(nil, 0).
count_nodes(tree(_Root, Children), N) :-
    maplist(count_nodes, Children, Ns), % call count_nodes, recursively, for each child
    sum_list([1|Ns], N).                % add 1 to count the root
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- count_nodes(nil, N).
N = 0.

?- count_nodes(tree(a,[]), N).
N = 1.

?- count_nodes(tree(a,[tree(b,[])]), N).
N = 2.

?- count_nodes(tree(a,[tree(b,[]),tree(c,[])]), N).
N = 3.

?- mytree(T), count_nodes(T, N).
T = tree(a, [tree(b, [tree(d, []), tree(e, [])]), tree(c, [tree(f, [])])]),
N = 6.
```